# Controlling spacing of histograms in Histogram3D

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have five histograms, `hist1 = Histogram[data1, 20]`,
to which I append `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` via `Data1 = Map[{#, 1} &, hist1]`, and then plot

---

[image: 3DHistogram]

---

```
Histogram3D[{Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4, Data5}, 10, 
  ChartLegends -> Etc, Boxed -> False, 
  FaceGrids -> {Bottom, Front, Left}, ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, None, Automatic}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x","y","z"}]
```

I cannot see how to control the width of the histograms (in the *y*-direction). Right now there is a gap between the 1st and the 2nd, etc.
What control am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some sample data along the lines of what I think you're using:

```
{data1, data2, data3, data4, data5} = 
    Table[{#, i} & /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[i, i], 100], {i, 5}];
```

Now when we generate a 3D histogram with 10 bins, we get gaps:

```
Histogram3D[{data1, data2, data3, data4, data5}, 10]
```

[image]

The reason for this is that your bin specification, `10`, gives ten bins in the $x$ direction, but also ten bins in the $y$ direction.  Since you only have five datasets, half the bins in the $y$ direction are completely empty.

A solution is to use a bin specification that better accounts for how you are constructing your datasets. In this case, I like `{10,{1}}`, which uses ten bins in the $x$ direction, and unit-spaced bins in the $y$ direction:

```
Histogram3D[{data1, data2, data3, data4, data5}, {10, {1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for the explanation of the meaning of `{10,{1}}`!

Answer (score 3):

Make the width `1`:

```
f[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}, {zmin_, zmax_}}, ___] := 
  Cuboid[{xmin, ymin, zmin}, {xmax, ymin + 1, zmax}];
Histogram3D[N@{Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4, Data5}, 10, Boxed -> False,
  FaceGrids -> {Bottom, Front, Left}, ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
 ChartElementFunction -> f, Ticks -> {Automatic, None, Automatic}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(Update: Originally, I doubled both widths.  Only one of the widths needed to be doubled, but setting it equal to `1` seemed much more natural.)

Comment: Great, Michael! Could I ask you to explain how you accomplished this? Is `ChartElementFunction` a `Cuboid` by default and you doubled it?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I eye-balled the (yes, default) cuboid being about half-width. Then I tried doubling it, following an example in the docs. I suppose because I'm busy with work, the simpler method of setting the width to `1` didn't occur to me until I woke up this worning.